# PowerShell Find Matching Folders and then move from src to destination

Tags: powershell, match, move, directory

I need to figure out the code to find matching folders in two directories.

```
Source Directory

Destination Directory
```

Once a match has been found I need to move the contents of the source directory to the destination directory and then delete the folder from the source directory. I only want this to happen if there is a matching folder on the destination directory that matches one in the source directory.

Folder names will be in a format of `3;15-cr-20154` or `23-5993`

The letters and number will be different everytime so I would need to search for that format of folder name ie:

```
[0-9];[0-9][0-9]-..-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].
```

Thank You for any help that you have.

Comment: I think this is unnessacrily complicated by including regex. There is no need for this if you are just comparing folder names.

Comment: Are you saying that the folders have similar names in source and destination? So one of the folders will have a different name but the components will be the same? I think you need to show us a better example of what you want

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of this pattern

```
(\d+;\d+-\w+-\d+)|(\d+-\d+)
```

See demo here https://regex101.com/r/wL4iL7/1

**Explanation**

```
(\d+;\d+-\w+-\d+): First group to be captured
(\d+-\d+): second group to be captured
```

**For first group**

```
\d+:matches all numbers
;:matches the semicolon
\d+-: matches all numbers and hyphen
\w+-\d+: matches words hyphen and numbers
```

**Second Group**

```
\d+-: matches all numbers and hyphen
\d+: matches the last set of numbers
```

Comment: I can find the folders and see them but I cant match them up and move the contents from the src to the destination

Comment: After reading the question I do not see how regex helps the OP or how this could answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is completly unessacary here. If you are just looking to copy when I match occurs then you just need to use a little PowerShell with the [`Compare-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx) cmdlet which would compare the lists. Even simpler would be just to use a where filter which is what we are going to do. Also going to assume that you don't need recurse logic since you didnt request it.

```
$sourceDirectory = "f:\temp\source"
$destinationDirectory = "f:\temp\destination"

$sourceFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectory | Where-Object{$_.PSisContainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$destinationFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationDirectory | Where-Object{$_.PSisContainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$matchesInBoth = $sourceFolders | Where-Object{$destinationFolders -contains $_}
$matchesInBoth | ForEach-Object{
    $sourcePath = (Join-Path $sourceDirectory $_)
    Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destinationDirectory -Force -Recurse
    Remove-Item $sourcePath -Force -Recurse #-WhatIf 
}
```

Get all of the file names in both direcories. For each directory that is in both we copy all the contents and remove the source directory.

Comment: I tried that but it just moved the folder from source to destination. it didn't match the folders when it moved it. I do need the -recurse object to search down the tree

Comment: I need you to clarify what the matches are supposed to be. The code I have moves the contents when the source and destination match

Comment: The matches will be the folder names itself. The source folder structure will be something like U:\Shared\Capture\ and then a bunch of sub folders with sub folders inside them. The destination folder is something like U:\Shared\Documents\ and then 3 or 4 layers of sub folders. I want it to match any sub folder name from the source to any sub folder in the destination. once it has a match then I want it to move the documents from the source folder it found to the destination folder that it matches. The file names are irrelevant in regards to matching the folder names.

Comment: Essentially the folders would stay where they are but the contents inside the source folder that matches the destination folder would be moved from the source to the destination.

Comment: @beaver So the matches are name =name and not some substring or things like that? What if there are multiple matches in a folder tree. If you remove a  folders contents it could remove another match deeper down. Or are you assuming that cannot happen? Basically what I have done is fine accept it is not recursive and you want to retain the folder yes?